# How to connect local printer to AWS RDP and then expose to network

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, printer, shared-printers

What I want to achieve is

Connect my home printer to a RDP in AWS then expose that printer to AWS VPC so any device connected to that VPC can send print jobs to the home printer.

What I don't want is
Not expose the printer in home network as it's not available for the current time.

Comment: Welcome to SF :) Please edit your question to make it more clear about your scenario. Are you wanting an AWS Windows server connected to an on-premise printer? If so you'll need a VPN.

Comment: @Tim done, can you help me with this

Comment: The option to share printer on network is greyed out and not available in windows server 2019 on AWS, I shared the local resources through RDP

Comment: I'm not a Microsoft / RDP expert, but I would probably set up a VPN to your home network or a device on the network then have the Windows server mount the printer. VPC resources talk to the Windows server, or even to the printer directly. The way you're doing seems a bit unusual to me.

Comment: Why connect it through the Windows Server at all? I mean, if you're already exposing the printer on the network why can't the other resources in the VPC go to it directly via IPP, LPR or some other means?

Comment: Its only connected to RDP and not exposed yet in VPC and the option is not working